# Linux out of tree module build issue

Tags: module, makefile, linux-kernel

```
obj-m := $(MODNAME).o
ccflags-y := $(CCFLAGS)
src_files := $(wildcard $(foreach pat,*.c *.cpp *.s,src/$(pat) src/$(MODNAME)/$(pat)))
$(MODNAME)-objs := $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(src_files)))

all:

    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:

    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

I have this make file for building kernel modules. However whenever I run it, I get an error saying that there is no rule to make target .c. .c is not a source file. If I remove the "if [ -d src ]" check then I get an error saying src doesn't exists on the recursive make call from the kernel build system. If I specify the full path to src it gives the same output saying that it can't find it (which is really weird). If I hard code src_files it works (if I didn't copy and paste wrong). Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your makefile you expect current directory to be the one contained given makefile. But when your file is executed from Kbuild context, this is no longer true: current directory is directory with *kernel sources*.

That is why content of `src_files` variable becomes wrong: `wildcard` cannot find files under *src/* in kernel sources. You may use special `src` variable for refer to directory with your makefile:

```
src_files := $(wildcard $(foreach pat,*.c *.cpp *.s,$(src)/src/$(pat) $(src)/src/$(MODNAME)/$(pat)))
```

From the other side, paths enumerated in `*-objs` variable should be *relative* (this is requirement by Kbuild). So you need to strip prefix from these absolute paths:

```
src_files_rel := $(src_files:$(src)/%=%)
```

Then you may use these paths for create objects list:

```
$(MODNAME)-objs := $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(src_files_rel)))
```

Comment: This seams to solve a lot of issues, but for some reason I'm still getting an issue. Below is a link to my Makefile and the output. Note that once again if a hard code in the source file it will fully build. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B59DI9U-fFzfWjNIMTZGSkJLZjQ

Comment: Oh, it was incorrect substitution reference usage in `src_files_rel` assignment: correct syntax `$(var:pattern=replacement)` uses `=` instead of `,` as a delimiter. The answer is fixed now.