# LKM Makefile, extract source files from source directories

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, makefile

I have the following project structure for a simple kernel module and I want to be able to build this by extracting the source files from the provided source directories in the Makefile.

```
Makefile
src/
    main.c
    sub_src/
        sub_src.c
        sub_src.h
```

I will describe my issue soon but I will first provide the code.

**main.c :**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

#include "sub_src/sub_src.h"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Unknown");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A Simple Hello World module");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
    sub_src_printk("sub_src.c\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

**sub_src.h :**

```
#ifndef __SUB_SRC_H___
#define __SUB_SRC_H___

#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
void  sub_src_printk( const char* );

#endif /* __SUB_SRC_H___ */
```

**sub_src.c :**

```
#include "sub_src.h"

void  sub_src_printk( const char* msg )
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s", msg);
}
```

**Makefile :**

```
MODULE_NAME ?= test_module
TEST        ?= 0 

INCLUDE_DIRS = -I$(src)/src/sub_src

ccflags-y := $(INCLUDE_DIRS)

ifeq ($(TEST), 1)
SRC_DIRS :=                     \
    src                         \
    src/sub_src
SRCS := $(foreach src_dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(src_dir)/*.c))
else
SRCS :=                         \
    src/main.c                  \
    src/sub_src/sub_src.c       
endif
#extract required object files
OBJ_SRCS :=  $(SRCS:.c=.o)

#setup kbuild
obj-m += $(MODULE_NAME).o
$(MODULE_NAME)-y := $(OBJ_SRCS)
$(MAKE) = make
KERNEL_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    @echo  ""
    @echo  "------- Building the LKM ($(MODULE_NAME).ko) -------"
    @echo  "INCLUDE_DIRS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS)"
    @echo  "SRCS = $(SRCS)"
    @echo  "OBJS_SRCS = $(OBJ_SRCS)"
    @echo  "ccflags-y = $(ccflags-y)"
    @echo  "obj-m = $(obj-m)"
    @echo  "test_module-y = $(test_module-y)"
    @echo  "-----------------------------------------------------"
    @echo  ""
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

The idea is that I should be able to build this module by providing only the source directories in the Makefile by calling make as:

```
make all TEST=1
```

But I have the option (for now) to provide the path to the source files by calling make as following:

```
make all TEST=0
```

These two calls should ideally provide the same result i.e a functional kernel module ready to be inserted (via sudo insmod ...). This is however not the case. (make all TEST=0 works as intended while make all TEST=1 does not)

**make all TEST=0 gives the following output:** (make clean has been called before this command)

```
------- Building the LKM (test_module.ko) -------
INCLUDE_DIRS = -I/src/sub_src
SRCS = src/main.c src/sub_src/sub_src.c         
OBJS_SRCS = src/main.o src/sub_src/sub_src.o
ccflags-y = -I/src/sub_src
obj-m = test_module.o
test_module-y = src/main.o src/sub_src/sub_src.o
-----------------------------------------------------

make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-59-generic/build   M=/home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-59-generic'
CC [M]  /home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test/src/main.o
CC [M]  /home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test/src/sub_src/sub_src.o
LD [M]  /home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test/test_module.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC      /home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test/test_module.mod.o
LD [M]  /home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test/test_module.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-59-generic'
```

**make all TEST=1 gives the following output:** (make clean has been called before this command)

```
------- Building the LKM (test_module.ko) -------
INCLUDE_DIRS = -I/src/sub_src
SRCS = src/main.c src/sub_src/sub_src.c
OBJS_SRCS = src/main.o src/sub_src/sub_src.o
ccflags-y = -I/src/sub_src
obj-m = test_module.o
test_module-y = src/main.o src/sub_src/sub_src.o
-----------------------------------------------------

make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-59-generic/build   M=/home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-59-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target  `/home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test/test_module.c', needed by   `/home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test/test_module.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/henrik/Desktop/test_lkm_dev/new_test]    Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-59-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The debugging info shows (as far I can see) that the variables in the Makefile contains the same values with the different approaches.

But the second alternative (TEST=1) somehow have the impression that there should be a source file called **test_module.c** which isn't the case.

Do someone/anyone have an idea why this happens and how I can solve it? (I have been pulling my hair out for the last two hours..)

**Solution (The Makefile):**

```
MODULE_NAME ?= test_module
TEST        ?= 0 

INCLUDE_DIRS = -I$(src)/src/sub_src
ccflags-y := $(INCLUDE_DIRS)

ifeq ($(TEST), 1)
# Paths to source directories
SRC_DIRS :=                     \
    src                         \
    src/sub_src
SRCS := $(foreach src_dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(src)/$(src_dir)/*.c))
SRCS := $(SRCS:$(src)/%=%)
else
SRCS :=                                 \
    src/main.c                          \
    src/sub_src/sub_src.c       
endif
# extract required object files
OBJ_SRCS :=  $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# setup kbuild
obj-m := $(MODULE_NAME).o
$(MODULE_NAME)-y := $(OBJ_SRCS)
$(MAKE) = make
KERNEL_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    @echo  ""
    @echo  "------- Building the LKM ($(MODULE_NAME).ko) -------"
ifeq ($(TEST), 1)
    @echo "Compiling with TEST = 1"
else
    @echo "Compiling with TEST = 0"
endif
    @echo  ""
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Many thanks! 
Henrik

Comment: The problem is same as in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428882/linux-out-of-tree-module-build-issue), asked today: when your makefile is parsed by Kbuild, current directory *is not the directory, contained your makefile*. Check my answer to that question for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am unfortunately not able to adapt that solution without getting the same error. I would appreciate if you could pinpoint where I need to make the appropriate changes (in my _Makefile) and to what exactly..

Comment: My answer for another question contained slightly incorrect code, now it is fixed. As for your Makefile, you need to prepend paths, searched by `$(wildcard)`, with `$(src)/`. After the search succeeds, you need to remove that prefix from resulted paths: `SRCS=$(SRCS:$(src)/%=%)`. Note, that output by your `echo` receipts will be incorrect, but `Kbuild` will get correct values of the variables.

Comment: Thanks, now it works :)